Ignore descendant rows in table hierarchy
Disclaimer I am fairly new to SSIS, so this might be a dumb question and there's plenty I don't know about SSIS. I'm painfully aware of that. So, please, keep it simple in the answers.
I am reading from an OData source where the records look like this:
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "name 1",
  "ParentId": 3
}

The other fields are of no consequence for the example.
There are several 'root' fields in the table, they have "ParentId": 0
My question is:
Given a root name (passed in as a parameter or hardwired or otherwise), is there a way to filter out all descendant rows (not just the children)?

Are you just looking for the records where ParentId = 0?  Is the OData source part of a data flow?

No I want to filter out records that descend from a given root, that is any record that has a designated root in it's parents chain.

To clarify, does "filter out" mean these are records you don't want?  By "from a given root" does this mean you want to send in a root name as a parameter?  How do you identify a parent, is this Id = ParentId?

Yes, once I identify the root I don't want to move forward with any records on it's descendants

Just add a filter in the dataflow where Id == ParentId

You probably want the "Conditional Split" task, but a few more details are needed before a real answer can be proposed. Do all the records that share a hierarchy have the same name? Or will you be using a root record's name for the filtering? If there's a name match, do you want to return the record where "ParentId": 0? If the name fields are not all the same for a given hierarchy, will you ever specify a non-root name that you want to filter on?
